# Make group by with linq and c # in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm a little new to this.

Someone to help me make a group by

ok what I want to group is by "id_levantamieto"

My code

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string Usuario = "";
        Usuario = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Usuario"].ToString();


        List<WebGridLevatamientos> list = new List<WebGridLevatamientos>();
        using (Web_INCAEntities dc = new Web_INCAEntities())
        {
            var v = (from a in dc.tbl_levantamiento
                     join b in dc.Cat_Proyecto on a.ProyectoID equals b.ID
                     where a.Usuario == Usuario
                     //group a by a.id_levantamiento into idGroup
                     select new WebGridLevatamientos
                     {
                         Id_Levantamiento = a.id_levantamiento,
                         ProyectoId = b.Nombre_Proyecto,
                         FechaImagen = a.FechaImagen
                     });
            list = v.ToList();
        }

        return View("../Levantamiento/FiltroLevantamiento", list);
    }
```

I was searching the web but so far nothing has worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
From the problem statement, i am not sure what is your expectation. But I believe you need to group both a and b. You might need to use something like this

var v = (from a in dc.tbl_levantamiento
join b in dc.Cat_Proyecto on a.ProyectoID equals b.ID
where a.Usuario == b.Usuario
group new{a,b} by a.id_levantamiento into idGroup
select new WebGridLevatamientos
{
Id_Levantamiento = idGroup.Key.id_levantamiento,
ProyectoId = idGroup.Select(x => x.b.ProyectoId ).FirstOrDefault(),//You should have an operation which works on an enumerable
FechaImagen = idGroup.Select(x => x.a.FechaImagen  ).FirstOrDefault()
```

});

Comment: the above link groups by "id_levantamiento". Did the above Linq help?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Status deleted
Error CS1061 "string" does not contain a definition for "id_levantamiento" nor is there any accessible "lift_id" extension method that accepts a first argument of type "string" (is any directive missing using or an assembly reference?)

Comment: sorry it should be just idGroup.Key

Comment: var v = (from a in dc.tbl_levantamiento
join b in dc.Cat_Proyecto on a.ProyectoID equals b.ID
where a.Usuario == b.Usuario
group new{a,b} by a.id_levantamiento into idGroup
select new WebGridLevatamientos
{
Id_Levantamiento = idGroup.Key,
ProyectoId = idGroup.Select(x => x.b.ProyectoId ).FirstOrDefault(),//You should have an operation which works on an enumerable
FechaImagen = idGroup.Select(x => x.a.FechaImagen  ).FirstOrDefault()